# 4 nodes to the internet, everything works except 3rd node

Tags: networking, route

I have 4 nodes to the internet:

```
Internet <--> Node A <--> Node B <--> Node C <--> Node D

Node A: main gateway, manage internet
Node B: gateway/tunnel to node C
Node C: gateway/tunnel to node B
Node D: FreeNAS server
```

Between B and C is a semi-private network. Default route on Node C is via the tunnel.

Can ping:

```
A: Internet, A, B, C, D
B: Internet, A, B, C, D
C: B, C, D
D: Internet, A, B, C, D
```

I really don't get it...

**edit**

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.20.1.1 (10.20.1.1)  0.959 ms  0.753 ms  0.535 ms
 2  10.20.200.1 (10.20.200.1)  4.993 ms  5.010 ms  4.804 ms
 3  10.20.2.1 (10.20.2.1)  5.152 ms  5.218 ms  5.046 ms
 4  modemcable233.11-37-24.static.videotron.ca (24.37.11.233)  5.638 ms  5.684 ms  5.645 ms
```

Traceroute from D to internet:
1: Node C
2: Node B (tunnel ip)
3: Node A
4: Internet

Comment: Check the default gateway on C

Comment: default GW on C is the IP of Node B's tunnel0 interface. D can ping internet via C whitout issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node A was missing a route to the tunnel between B and C.

Pings went from C->B->A->Internet->Internet

Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

probably the gateway on C.

`netstat -nr` will show you what gateways are in the route table.

you should see

`0.0.0.0 <gatewayaddress>`

If it is not there, then add it into the Ethernet adapter settings.

Comment: it's there: `0.0.0.0         10.20.200.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tunnel0`

Comment: if that is your correct gateway then make sure you have the nameservers setup properly. Try pinging the google dns servers, but the ip `ping 8.8.8.8`. if the ip pings, then it is probably no dns being picked up.